# MYSQL - Is there a way to select sql records and then update it in a single query

Tags: java, mysql

This transaction is working in MySQL. But I want this transaction in a single query to forward selected records(`ResultSet`) and then update THE value 0 to 1 in THE table.

```
START TRANSACTION;
select    [col1]    [col3]    from    [table1]    where    [col1]    =    0 ;
UPDATE    [table1]    SET    [col1]    =    1    where    [col1]    =    0;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: For the update in you transaction you don't need the select  just perform the  the update .

Comment: I am not selecting it to update. I need to show the data which is selected.

Comment: then you need a select ? .. and show the data in java?

Comment: I want to maintain record that,  which records are shown and which is not. So both queries are necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for my query. Actually I am using JDBC importer script file to set data in elasticsearch from MYSQL. And I got errors while using two queries in script file. This is the answer to execute it.

```
"sql" : [
        {
            "statement" :    "SELECT    [col1],    [col3]    FROM    [table1]    where     [col1]    =    0"
        },
        {
            "statement" :    "update    [table1]    set    [col1]    =    1    where    [col1]    =    0"
        }
    ],
```